# Maven Multi-module build problem does not resolve property properly

Tags: maven

I have a simple Maven Multi Module project.

The only real distinguishing characteristic of this is that I have a `revision` property to manage the versions in the project. You can see how in PomMod2 I have a dependency on PomMod1, that uses the `revision` property to specify the version number.

If you build (`mvn clean install`)this project from the top level, it builds all of the modules just fine.

But if you build the PomMod2 project on its own, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PomMod2: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project pkg.pomtest.pommod2:PomMod2:jar:1.2.3: Failed to collect dependencies at 
pkg.pomtest.pommod1:PomMod1:jar:1.2.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
pkg.pomtest.pommod1:PomMod1:jar:1.2.3: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
pkg.pomtest:PomTest:pom:${revision} (absent): Could not find artifact 
pkg.pomtest:PomTest:pom:${revision} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

It's clearly not properly dereferencing the `revision` property. But it was my understanding the properties in the parent are included in child projects. So I don't understand why this fails stand alone, yet works from the parent.

The Parent pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pkg.pomtest</groupId>
  <artifactId>PomTest</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <revision>1.2.3</revision>
  </properties>
  <modules>
    <module>PomMod1</module>
    <module>PomMod2</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

PomMod1 pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>pkg.pomtest</groupId>
        <artifactId>PomTest</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>pkg.pomtest.pommod1</groupId>
    <artifactId>PomMod1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

PomMod2 pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>pkg.pomtest</groupId>
        <artifactId>PomTest</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>pkg.pomtest.pommod2</groupId>
    <artifactId>PomMod2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pkg.pomtest.pommod1</groupId>
            <artifactId>PomMod1</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: If you like to use `${revision}` you have to use the `flatten-maven-plugin`... check the docs https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html and read until the end...